# Get ip-address of local NIC from kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am writing a kernel module which forms its own packet at ip level and then sends the data . I just want to know how to find the ip address of a local network interface.

Comment: A network interface can (and will) receive  packets from many different senders. You get the sender from the received packet.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I want the ip address for my interface . Is there no function of getting a ip address for my interface . I dont want to capture rx packet and take from there as I would be generating traffic

Comment: I edited the question and title to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are defined ioctls `SIOCGIFADDR` (to get if address) and `SIOCSIFADDR` (to set if address).

All device configuration for IPv4 is done in `net/ipv4/devinet.c`. You can refer to this source file to get more information.

Comment: I want to use ioctl for ip address in kernel space .....how could i do it ..please tell by writing a code

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to read interface addresses reeks of a design problem. However, if you are looking for determining the preferred source address to use when contacting a remote peer is given in `struct rt6_info.rt6i_prefsrc` after obtaining it with `ip6_route_output`. Something along the lines of (with no implied guarantees):

```
int pick_addr(struct in6_addr *saddr, struct net *net, const struct in6_addr *daddr)
{
    struct rt6_info *rt;
    struct flowi6 fl6;
    int ret;
    memset(&fl6, 0, sizeof(fl6));
    memcpy(&fl6.daddr, daddr, sizeof(*daddr));
    dst = (struct rt6_info *)ip6_route_output(net, NULL /* or sk if you have it */, &fl6);
    ret = rt->dst.error;
    if (ret == 0)
            memcpy(saddr, &rt->rt6i_prefsrc.addr, sizeof(*saddr));

    dst_release(&rt->dst);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It's similar for IPv4 (see net/netfilter/xt_TEE.c for the skeleton). prefaddr is then in `struct rtable.rt_src` AFAICS.

Answer (score 0):

We have **if_getconfig** function available in  *linux-x.y.z/Documentation/networking/ifenslave.c* file which is a very good example of how to use ioctls and fetch address from kernel space